# Implementing custom ListView for chat app

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing a kinda chat app and want to use a `ListView` for displaying messages. Currently I'm trying to get user's input and display it as an "outgoing message". My `row` layout is following: `TextView`(timestamp), `TextView`(message), `ImageView`(message state indicator). My problem: the text and timestamp are not getting set, just a "dummy" layout is inflated. I guess I have to set the text inside the adapter somehow.. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code is below.

my Adapter:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

private List<String> chat;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<String> listchat) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chat = listchat;
}

public int getCount() {
    return chat.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return chat.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    TextView tvTS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTS);
    // TODO set timestamp

    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    // TODO set the text to the actual message text from etInput

    ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgInd);

    // TODO set the image Resource according to message state
    return convertView;
}
```

my Activity:

```
 public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

private EditText input;
private String tmpMessage;
ListView lv;
ChatAdapter adapter;
List<String> messages;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lis);
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    lv = getListView();

    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, messages);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

public void sendMessage() {

    tmpMessage = input.getText().toString();
    input.setText("");
    messages.add(tmpMessage);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public String generateTimestamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String ts = sdf.format(new Date());

    return ts;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I added a holder and set the text using the following code:

```
 String message = (String) getItem(position);
        holder.message.setText(message);
```

it works but the inflated layouts now get positioned randomly, see a screenshot below. It should look like

test

test1

test2

....

[image]

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting the data to the TextViews/ImageView. You need to do this in the getView() method of your ChatAdapter, as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    String chatMessage = getItem(position);
    TextView tvTS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTS);
    // TODO set timestamp

    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    //Set the message to the TextView
    tvMessage.setText(chatMessage);

    ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgInd);

    // TODO set the image Resource according to message state
    return convertView;
}
```

Consider using a custom Object (instead of a list of Strings) to hold the message, timestamp and the type of message state indicator to be displayed. In that case, you could do this

```
ChatMessage msgObj = getItem(position);
...
tvMessage.setText(msgObj.getMessage());
tvTS.setText(msgObj.getTimestamp());
if ( msgObj.getStatus() == ChatMessage.DELIVERED )
{
  indicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delivered);
}
else if (....)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `setText` method in your `getView` for text method and set the text for each View you need. And also set your image. `getView` is responsible for creating a single View for the list, so you have to implement it in the way that it returns a ready View each time.

What you are doing now is just finding elements by their id and doing nothing with them. You just return the default inflated row.

P.S. Read also about ViewHolder pattern for performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

try the following changes in your getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

 TextView tvTS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTS);    

 TextView tvMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

 ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgInd);

}   
tvMessage.setText("......");

return convertView;
```

}

[Please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166092/how-to-insert-the-data-from-the-adapter-to-the-listview)

Comment: the problem is that I have to pass the message string to the getView method each time it is called. Don't get how to do this from my ChatActivity class..

Comment: I guess you cannot pass message to the getview method. You can just change the adapter. and after changing the adapter call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by changing the adapter please?

Comment: I have attached a link.. you can check that link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ViewHolder pattern for better performance on your list

ViewHolder class:

```
public class ViewHolder{
public TextView message;
public TextView timestamp;
public ImageView indicator
}
```

then in your Adapter getView Method use it the following way:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null ){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_layout>, null);           

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
holder.indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

            holder.message.setText(chat.get(position).<whatever>);
            holder.timestamp.setText(chat.get(position).<whatever>);
holder.indicator.<method>
            return convertView;
}
```

Hope that helps.

BR,
mybecks